# Ms Access control.left throws overflow error on large monitors

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a large monitor and I'm trying to place a control at a specific location on the screen.

The following code throws an `overflow` error as the `control.Left` property is an ancient `integer` type. I have a 4k monitor and the `Me.InsideWidth - Me.Command0.Width` returns a value larger than  33k in twips

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
    Me.Command0.Left = Me.InsideWidth - Me.Command0.Width
End Sub
```

I cannot use the `Anchoring` facility as it doesn't allow me to place a control where I want.

I've seen someone posted a similar question in 2015 in MSDN but no accepted answer was given. Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Comment: This a know issue, sadly not to be expected to be resolved in the near future. So, add some error handling to avoid the overflow error.

Comment: :(. is it possible to somehow set the value in `cm` like shown in the property window?

Comment: No. That setting is a display thing.